# How to sort span column header using table sort script

Tags: jquery, datatables, tablesorter

I'm trying to sort the html table, like below

[image]

I like to sort when click on table header (Person,User#, UniqueID ,Full Name, Trans No., Flags, In and Out).

How to sort when click on User# as well as UniqueID column using table sort?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's still not perfect, but I have a fork of tablesorter on github which is able to sort columns underneath the clicked column... try the "Full Name" header cell to see what I mean. I'll need to fix the way it updates the css in the "Product" and "In" columns.

Anyway, [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/116/) using the information from the image above. It's using the undocumented `cssChildRow` option - see the [original demo here](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm). The code from that second demo was added to tablesorter 2.0.5. And [here is the same demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/117/) using the original tablesorter... you can see that clicking on the "Full Name" column will only sort the "ID#" column

Comment: Hi Mottie Thanks for your reply, I tried some but not working still, here is a demo link http://jsfiddle.net/prabud/wB8bk/
any suggestion ?

Comment: Lets try with http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm

Comment: I had to add the `expand-child` class to the extra table rows - the ones directly below the rows with `rowspan="2"` (but only in the tbody). Here is an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/wB8bk/5/)

Comment: still the header 'In' and 'Out' is not seen to be work properly. What should I have to do for that columns?

Comment: Honestly, I think the best solution would be to add In/OUt to one cell and set it to `rowspan="2"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I involved to convert Multi column .NET GridView into Mobile web view. so that I added column span for table header. any idea or suggestions might be helpful. Thanks!.